# PostgreSQL: Why can I connect to a user with a set password without having to give the password?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, passwords

After creating a new user `john` with:

```
CREATE USER john PASSWORD 'test';
CREATE DATABASE johndb OWNER john;
```

I can connect to the PostgreSQL server with:

```
psql -U john johndb
```

The problem is that `psql` never asks me for the password. I realy need to know what's wrong, because of obvious reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `pg_hba.conf` file probably has local connections set to "trust". The default contains a section like this:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

This means that for all connections from the local machine, trust whatever the client says. If the client says "I am user john", then the server will permit that.

The PostgreSQL documentation has a whole [section on the `pg_hba.conf` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: I have a similar problem but mine nothing is set to trust and using psql it asks for a password but if you use psycog2 API you can get through without one, why?

Comment: @radtek: I don't know for sure, but perhaps psycog2 is using a different connection method that automatically authenticates the current user to the postgresql server.

Comment: I forgot I had the .pgpass file in my home directory. If you don't specify a password, psycopg2 uses the info stored in .pgpass as does psql